# Teste de conexão

Tags: android, conexão

Tenho uma aplicação que irá enviar alguns pacotes ao servidor.

Gostaria de antes de enviar, verificar se o servidor está disponível. E, para isso, fiz o seguinte:

```
   public static boolean isConnect(){

        boolean isOn = false;
        try{
            final String command = "/system/bin/ping -c 1 "+HOST;
            int wait = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor();
            Log.d(TAG,"wait: "+wait);
            isOn = ( wait == 0);
        }catch (final Exception e){}
        Log.d(TAG,"Connect: "+isOn);
        return isOn;
    }
```

Mas em todos os casos ele sempre retorna 1.

Segundo a documentação:

> the exit value of the native process being waited on.

Isto pode variar, se estou usando 3G?

Ou qual a melhor forma de fazer este teste?

Não quero saber se tenho conexão com a internet, e sim se o HOST está respondendo!

Comment: Como assim "Isto pode variar, se estou usando 3g?"

Comment: Simplesmente faça o que tiver que fazer e trate o erro. Não há vantagem nenhum em fazer esse teste toda vez que você precisar acessar seu host. Ele tem por obrigação estar sempre disponível.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa , sendo  a 3g mais demorada, o tempo de retorno entre 3g e Wifi podem ser diferentes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade o método funciona corretamente, o problema é que o `HOST` não aceita  ping!