# Teste de conexão com internet eficaz

Tags: java, android, conexão

Tenho uma aplicação no qual faço um teste de conexão antes de consultar um *webservice*, justamente para exibir uma mensagem para usuário que não possui conexão com internet. Uso um método desta forma:

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Percebi nesta pergunta sobre [Testar conexao com a internet de uma aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29358/testar-conexao-com-a-internet-de-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) que é usado o `Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE`, como na minha função. Baseado em alguns testes que fiz, desta forma como é feita, se estiver apenas conectado ao WIFI ou 4G, é detectado que possui uma conexão, porém nem sempre funciona, pois em alguns casos acaba caindo numa **INTRANET**. Pode ser uma forma eficiente, mas não necessariamente tão eficaz.

Vi essa resposta sobre [Texte de Contexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103132/teste-de-conex%C3%A3o) que é possível dar um *ping* no ***HOST***, porém de acordo com a resposta validada, nem sempre os *hosts* aceitam *pings*.

Tento toda esse questionamento, qual seria a forma mais eficaz de testar se existe uma conexão com internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma coisa é ter uma conexão activa à rede(*network*) outra é conseguir aceder a um recurso na internet.

A verificação da existência de uma conexão activa pode ser feita com o código colocado na pergunta.

Eu apenas alterava

```
if (null != activeNetwork)
```

para

```
if (null != activeNetwork && activeNetwork.isConnected())
```

ficará assim:

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Caso essa verificação falhe deve informar o utilizador da necessidade da conexão e, eventualmente, pedir-lhe que ligue o wifi, direccionando-o para as *Settings*, usando

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Verificar se um recurso na internet é acessível ou não depende do recurso em si. Por isso não é possível escrever um método que garanta a 100% que um qualquer recurso está acessível.
Usar *ping* ou verificar se o endereço da google está acessível apenas garante isso mesmo: que o servidor "pingado" ou o servidor da Google estão acessíveis, não garante que o seu serviço ou qualquer outro esteja.

Assim, nos termos que refere, não há um método único e eficaz de verificar a conexão à internet.
A abordagem a seguir é verificar se há uma conexão activa e, em cada caso, o código que acede ao recurso, lidar com o facto de ele poder não estar acessível.

Comment: Tinha me esquecido desta pergunta! Obrigado. =D